# How should I handle maintaining row Identity for new records in Linq / Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework, identity, identity-column

What is the proper way to create a new unique shared key when using Linq and EF with SQL?

I could use a GUID upon inserting the record but I only want want my keys to have 7 digits or characters in it as they will appear in the URL of my MVC application.  If this isn't an option, or it's just better with GUID's let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by "shared" key?

Comment: I mean that a shared key is a key that may (or may not) be used as a FK, in other tables.  Maybe that will occur as a part of this insert, maybe a part of another insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need a unique key across machine boundaries then I would just go with a `bigint`/idenity that auto-increments by 1 (which is the default). You do not have to specify the identity when adding a new entity with EF, it will be auto-assigned. Once it has been assigned you can then use it as a FK.

In my opinion `GUIDs` are only useful in this context if you have to guarantee that the key is unique across multiple databases, i.e. you create they key on one machine (A) and want to transfer the data to another machine (B), retaining the key. This is not possible with `bigint` keys since machine B might have inserted other data with the same key already.

Comment: How do I use an auto-incrementing key in a new PK/FK relationship, using Linq or Entity Framework, where EF hides and abstracts the FK into an object ?

Comment: Define a FK relationship in your DB/model, this will be reflected in your Entities with a navigation property (let's say Entity `B` has FK relationship with Entity `A`). When you add a new Entity `B`, just set the corresponding navigation property, i.e. set `B.A =A` then add the object and do a `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: When I add new entity `B` how do I get the autoIncrement result of that key for use within `A`? Are you saying that the EF takes care of that magically for me?  Is the constraint that the PK is an identity column?  What supporting configuration (besides the FK relationship and navigation) needs to be done on the SQL table?  Who is making the identity key SQL, EF, my code?

Comment: I'm saying that the navigation property represents the FK relationship (otherwise you wouldn't get the navigation property). So if you set `B.A = A` that will be translated to setting the foreign key for `B` to the id of `A` in SQL. In EF you should worry about entity relationships not FKs directly. Try it out in a simple scenario with 2 entities!